# Problem with vector<T>.erase() with g++

Tags: c++, vector

The following code builds error free on msvc, but does not compile on g++.

```
         if(*it == listener){
            it = listeners.erase(it);
        }
```

The error is in erase,
The full code is:

```
void AguiListener::removeListener( AguiWidget* listener )
{
    for(std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_iterator it = listeners.begin(); 
        it != listeners.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it == listener){
            it = listeners.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
```

and listeners is:

```
std::vector<AguiWidget*> listeners;
```

but g++ spits out loads of errors:

> `AguiListener.cpp:29: error: no`
>   `matching function for call to`
>   `‘std::vector<AguiWidget*,`
>   `std::allocator<AguiWidget*>`
>   `>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<AguiWidget*`
>   `const*, std::vector<AguiWidget*,`
>   `std::allocator<AguiWidget*> > >&)’`
>   `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/vector.tcc:109:`
>   `note: candidates are: typename`
>   `std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator`
>   `std::vector<_Tp,`
>   `_Alloc>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename`
>   `std::_Vector_base<_Tp,`
>   `_Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >) [with _Tp`
>   `= AguiWidget*, _Alloc = std::allocator<AguiWidget*>]`
>   `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/vector.tcc:121:`
>   `note:                 typename`
>   `std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator`
>   `std::vector<_Tp,`
>   `_Alloc>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename`
>   `std::_Vector_base<_Tp,`
>   `_Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >,`
>   `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp,`
>   `_Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >) [with _Tp`
>   `= AguiWidget*, _Alloc = std::allocator<AguiWidget*>]`

What could be wrong with this? Also, why would it work on msvc but not g++?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the current C++ standard (C++03), `std::vector::erase` takes an `iterator`, not a `const_iterator`.

In the forthcoming C++ standard (C++0x), `std::vector::erase` takes a `const_iterator`.  The Visual C++ Standard Library implementation already supports this (at least it does in  the latest version, Visual C++ 2010).

Comment: can I just type cast the problem away?

Comment: @Milo:  No.  You should use an `iterator`.

Comment: @Chubsdad:  What sounds strange and why is what so?  (Your comment would be much improved if you added some nouns to it.)

Comment: : ). why a const iterator is allowed to erase elements from a vector? It sounds a little strange to me at least.

Comment: @Chubsdad:  Because the constness of a `const_iterator` means that the element to which it refers cannot be modified.  It doesn't affect the constness of the container.